# make multiple pthreads wait on same condition , all awakened by thread zero

Tags: c, pthreads

Case is : There are multiple (say n^2) pthreads all derived from same function.
Pthread with id zero is master .
Each pthread (other than zero) has a for loop which runs n times

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{   pthread_mutex_lock(&conditionmutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&conditionmutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&conditionmutex);
    do something;
}
```

For thread zero it is

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{   pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
    do something else;
}
```

I expected that each pthread (other than zero) will wait at the beginning of for loop.
Thread zero will signal then all other threads will 'do something'
and then wait again at beginning of loop with incremented value of j.
My program gets stuck at beginning itself.
Can't find out the cause.

Thanks.

PS:cv is condition variable initialized to NULL , similiarly for mutex variable 'conditionmutex'.

```
pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&conditionmutex, NULL);
```

I have put up a barrier of n^2 threads before for loop in function.
This ensures that all threads are created and waiting before for loop.

I want to know - if my method is ok ?

Comment: You need to show us a complete MCVE.  There is insufficient information here - could be a number of errors.

Comment: You want to lock the mutex just before broadcasting and unlock it right after.